# Not Condition In xpath

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have the following xml :

```
<test1>
    <test2>
       <text>This is a question on xpath
       </text>
    </test2>
    <test3>
        <test2>
            <text>Do not extract this
             </text>
        </test2>
    </test3>
</test1>
```

I need to extract text within `test2/text` but not if `test2` comes inside `test3`. How can this be done in xpath ? I tried with `findall` with something like:

```
for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//test2',namespaces={'w':w}):
    for q in p.iterancestors():
        if q.tag=="test3":
           break
        else:
            text+= ''.join(t.text for t in p.xpath('.//text'))
```

but this doesn't work . I guess xpath has a better way in a single expression to exclude it.

Expected output:

```
text = "This is a question on xpath"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by `comes inside` you mean any level of parent, you can use `not` with the [`ancestor` axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) to check to see whether a node does not have a specific parent / ancestor:

```
//test2[not(ancestor::test3)]/text
```

If however you meant `immediate parent` should not be `test3`, then switch `ancestor` for `parent`:

```
//test2[not(parent::test3)]/text
```

Comment: I'm no pythonista, but the result is a `nodeset`, and lxml seems a robust library, so I would imagine this can be used as `for p in lxml_tree.xpath('.//test2[not(ancestor::test3)]/text')`